# How to retrieve conversations and replies of old tweets using Tweepy from conversation_id?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have the Academic Research access to Twitter's API and have been using Tweepy to access the API. My problem is I cannot retrieve the tweets from older tweets

This is the code attempting to retrieve the tweets using the conversation_id, from 2014

```
# https://twitter.com/NintendoAmerica/status/535462600294035456
start_time = '2014-11-01T00:00:00Z'
end_time = '2014-12-12T00:00:00Z'
tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query = 'conversation_id:535462600294035456', max_results = 500, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time)
```

and the output is:

```
Response(data=[<Tweet id=535465221679489024 text='@NintendoAmerica @Pokemon [this was a link I had to remove]'>], includes={}, errors=[], meta={'newest_id': '535465221679489024', 'oldest_id': '535465221679489024', 'result_count': 1})
```

which is only one seemingly random tweet amongst many.
However, when I tried running the same code on a more recent tweet, it retrieved all the tweets. I do not have to specify a start/end time because it's a tweet from the past 30 days.

```
# https://twitter.com/380kmh/status/1545477360916373504
tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query = 'conversation_id:1545477360916373504', max_results = 500)
```

the output was complete (shortened, I removed the tweets):

```
Response(data=[...], meta={'newest_id': '1546465585093087235', 'oldest_id': '1545477768229670912', 'result_count': 18})
```

I followed Tweepy's documentation here, using Client.search_all_tweets:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_all_tweets

I also tried using Postman to retrieve the tweets but it came out empty, even though I followed the documentation here:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all#tab0

Query: https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?query=conversation_id%3A537923834557771776&start_time=2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z&end_time=2014-12-18T00:00:00.000Z&tweet.fields=in_reply_to_user_id,text

Output:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "result_count": 0
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?